# SetValue Completion Block with Firebase 3.x

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, completionhandler

In Firebase 2.5.1, this was working:

```
let post1Ref = sendRequestRef.childByAutoId()
post1Ref.setValue(request, withCompletionBlock: {( error:NSError?, ref:Firebase!) in

})
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to achieve it in 3.x (as the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data#delete_data) for completion doesn't really tell it)

```
let post1Ref = sendRequestRef.childByAutoId()
post1Ref.setValue(request, withCompletionBlock: {( error:NSError?, ref:Firebase!) in
    if (error != nil) {
       print("ERROR")
    } else {
       print("Success")
    }
})
```

This throws an error:

> Use of unresolved Firebase

What is the proper way of handling completion block with Firebase 3.x?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use

```
ref.setValue(object) { (error, ref) -> Void in

}
```

Here ref is **FIRDatabaseReference**